# Limit Charging Current of a 3.7 V, 300 mAh Lipo Battery

Tags: battery-charging, lipo, tp4056

[image: Lipo Battery]

My Lipo battery is 3.7 V, 300 mAh and the charging current normally is 1C (300 mA). I am using a charging module [TP4056](http://www.tp4056.com/d/tp4056.pdf) rated at 5 V and charging current is 1 A. This is obviously more than 1C.

[image: TP4056]

My question is, if I use a phone charger with a 5 V, 300 mA rating (if I could find it), I do not have to desolder the 1.2 kΩ resistor and solder a 4 kΩ resistor to the TP4056 to achieve 300 mA, right?

Because I am thinking that when the input is only 300 mA, the maximum current draw from the source during charging is also 300 mA. The current will not go beyond that. Am I right?

Comment: You also should read this https://www.best-microcontroller-projects.com/tp4056.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that won't work.

The charger will try to draw 1A to charge the battery, but if the power supply can only provide 300mA, it can't provide the 1A to load and it can shut down due to overcurrent or reduce the output voltage which won't be enough to charge the battery.

Comment: So I still have to change the 1.2 kΩ to 4 kΩ to get it 300mA?